# How to set the date forward on a linux server and prevent it from resetting back to the correct time

Tags: ubuntu, time

I need to set the time on an Ubuntu Server forward 1 week, and keep it there (this is for a testing environment with date-specific conditions which need to be tested/verified by the stakeholders), however when I do this (with `date -s 2010-11-11T00:00:00`) the time resets back to the 'real' value after about 30 minutes.

I have disabled `NTP`, `ntpdate` etc, even removed the NTP packages, disabled `munin-node` for monitoring et-al, but it still happens and I can't seem to figure out what is happening.

I tried setting up a script to keep the time shifted forward every minute bit it causes weird behavior/issues with Nginx and Varnish when it switches back and forward between the script runs.

Any advice?

(Sidenote: this is an Ubuntu 9.10, running on EC2)

**Additional Info**: There are no cron jobs running relating to time, and I am unable to access the hardware clock to try and push that forward and use that as the source....

I am kind of thinking that this is one of the idioms of EC2 - you get a 'really reliable' clock, regardless of what you do...

Comment: Try to look for messages in /var/log that are related to time. Do you have custom scripts doing things? grep them all for date/ntpdate/etc.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that any virtual machine guest additions on EC2 are performing time sync with the host independent of NTP?

Answer (score 1):

If there are only a few processes that you need to lie to you could use [libfaketime](https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime):

> libfaketime intercepts various system calls which programs use to
>   retrieve the current date and time. It can then report faked dates and times
>   (as specified by you, the user) to these programs. This means you can modify
>   the system time a program sees without having to change the time system-wide.

Answer (score 0):

Check out /etc/cron.d and /etc/cron.hourly, you should find something there. grep for ntpdate and/or hwclock.

If you already removed the ntp package, then it is likely to be the hardware clock (hwclock) being synchronized.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that I can't access the hwclock - I was thinking that perhaps the host of the VMs is updating the hardware clock. Problem is that I can't see /dev/rtc* anywhere and hwclock raises errors about that

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix might be to set your timezone to one hour ahead of where you are now (+10 to +11, or -8 to -7 for example)? That way, the next time your clock syncs it will still have the "wrong" time.

Comment: The times in our application are using time zones already, which in the end is converted back to UTC, so setting the timezone forward won't help in this instance.

Comment: @Matthew - Oh well!

Comment: Thanks anyways - damn timezone logic getting in the way of things!